Using the derivative, find $a$ such that: $|x-a| = (x-2)^2$
So I've been studying Jay Cummings's Real Analysis book, and I've encountered this problem:
Use the derivative to find all values of $ a $ such that the following holds: $$|x-a| = (x-2)^2 $$
He doesn't explicitly mention that it should hold for all values of $x$. Although the solution is trivial: $$ a = x \pm (x-2)^2 $$ I really do not understand how come one uses the derivative for this.
The reader is assumed to only know notions such as continuity and elementary set theory.
As an update regarding this problem, it seems that it is indeed an error. The reader who wants to check the errors in Jay Cummings's Real Analysis book should look here: https://longformmath.com/analysis-errata

Please reread the problem from the book, I'm pretty sure you missed something. It's possible but highly unusual that $x$ is a parameter and $a$ the value you are looking for. Naming conventions would indicate the opposite interpretation. But the mentioning of a derivative indicates that this is not something that holds for a few values of $x$, but something that holds for all $x$. In which case, there is no solution.

@Ingix The exercise in the book is exactly as OP stated. Probably something is missing in the book itself.

@jjagmath Thanks for checking that. Maybe the $|x-a|$ misses a squaring, but that still wouldn't explain the hint about the derivates.
